# Searching value in a matrix Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet in which I have a table like this:

```
+--------+------------+---+---+---+
| Name A | Category A | 3 | 0 | 0 |
+--------+------------+---+---+---+
| Name B | Category B | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| Name C | Category C | 2 | 6 | 0 |
+--------+------------+---+---+---+
```

In another sheet of the same file I need a function to find each number and insert in the cell the Name of that record line.

For example for number 4 I will receive Name B.
The problem is that I can't find a function that is able to find in a matrix.
The 0 I put here are void cells and I don't need to find them.
I'm sure that every number isn't repeated.

Comment: Welcome. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,{D:D,B:B},2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,{E:E,B:B},2,0),VLOOKUP(H2,{F:F,B:B},2,0)))
```

Or you could also use this formula:

```
=UNIQUE({B:C,D:D;B:C,E:E;B:C,F:F})
```

to convert matrix into long data format and simply use vlookup.

[image]

Comment: Both the solutions don't work. The first one because Google Sheet doesn't allow me to set an interval like C:A, he corrects automatically in A:C. The second one also gives me problem by saying I can put only one argument.  Here is an example of what I need in a clear way I hope. Maybe you can help me more with more details [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z9S5GkZgRxCX_v51Fui1kOKYeNABjosLA6vraa1w7wg/edit#gid=0)

Really appreciate you help, thanks a lot.